# JS,CSS) get letters from String and make to fall down each letters smoothly(NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript, css, transition

Hi I need a some funny text animation for my site.

For example falling letters.

If I use Word 'Stackoverflow' ,

First letter (S) will fall down, after that when the first one is finished

second letter (t) will fall down, after that third one (a)...

repeat until the last letter falls down.

With my code/jsfiddle below it does not work as expected.

This is my code:

```
var textDOM = document.querySelector('#home p');
function appendLetters(target,text,index){
    if(index<text.length){
        textDOM.innerHTML+='<span>'+text[index++]+'</span>';

        setTimeout(function(){
            textDOM.lastChild.classList.add('index-'+index);
            appendLetters(target,text,index)
        },1000);

    }
}

(function(){
    console.log(appendLetters);
    appendLetters('#home p', 'a simple site made by an web developer',0);
}())
```

css:

```
#home p span{
position:relative;
top:-60px;
/*animation:fallLetters 0.2s;*/
transition: top 0.8s linear;
}
#home p span[class^='index-']{
    top:0px;
}
```

Because transition-delay of span tags are 0.8s, changing their css top value "completely" should take 800ms.

But with my code all letters except the last one don't want to fall down smoothly. Have no idea why.

http://jsfiddle.net/1fcgv0ta/

You see only the last one falls down smoothly but all letters should fall down smoothly.. How to fix my code without JQUERY?

There is no room for JQuery in my project.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is entirely because you are updating the DOM through appending to the `innerHTML` property using `+=`. I've actually read before about this being discouraged, but had never actually realised why until analysing your code here! (The reason being I tend to always use jQuery for straight DOM-manipulation tasks, so aren't as familiar with the vanilla DOM API - that's irrelevant for the answer though of course!)

Anyway, saying:

```
node.innerHTML += myHTMLString;
```

is of course equivalent to:

```
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + myHTMLString;
```

But writing it longhand makes it clearer that you aren't actually really "adding" to the `innerHTML`. You're just *replacing* it by brand new HTML content - which "just so happens" to be the original content with a new element added.

Why does this matter here? It matters because you're using CSS transitions. The "falling" effect you want will only happen when one of your `<span>` elements gets one of the `index-*` classes added to it. [Side note, there's no reason not to just use a single class for this.] Now, you are of course adding this class in your code - but immediately afterwards, you call `appendLetters` again, which as I've just pointed out, clears the entire content of `textDOM` and replaces it by new content. As a result, the transition doesn't actually happen, because there is nothing to transition from - a `<span class="index-1">` (for example) has just appeared from nowhere, which has a CSS `top` value of `0px`. Yes, it has a `transition` property too, but since the element effectively didn't exist before, there's nothing to transition *from*, so it "just appears" in what you would like to be its final position.

This also tells you why it *was* working for the final letter (the `e`). Although `appendLetters` is called afterwards, the `if` check fails, so you don't then update the DOM - so the old DOM isn't destroyed and replaced by a new one, and the transition functions as planned.

Phew - I've gone one for much longer than I meant to, but I hope you appreciate the (hopefully) clear explanation.

The fix, as I'm sure you will have realised, is to update the DOM in a way that *appends* the new element to it, rather than destroy-then-recreate as you are doing so far. So instead of the offending line:

```
textDOM.innerHTML+='<span>'+text[index++]+'</span>';
```

do this instead:

```
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.innerHTML = text[index++];
textDOM.appendChild(newSpan);
```

Hope this sorts out your problem - if it does and you appreciate the explanation, please give me a vote :)

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation. Works great

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if it is a nice solution, but fixed by creating another setTimeout function in setTimeout function and called appendLetters in nested setTimeout function.

```
        setTimeout(function(){
            textDOM.lastChild.classList.add('index-'+index);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    appendLetters(target,text,index)
                },400);
        },200);
```

Not sure why this fixed but this fixed...

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. (On Chrome, anyway - haven't tried other browsers, but can't see why modern browsers should behave differently from each other with this.) [But I still don't know how to fix it or why the OP's code doesn't work, I've been thinking about it and trying things, on and off, for quite a while!]

Comment: (actually I figured it out, see the answer which I'm about to post. This answer unfortunately definitely doesn't fix the actual issue)